# Can function specialization be accomplished without a trait?

Tags: rust

Can function specialization be accomplished without the use of a trait?  Using the unstable specialization feature, the following code accomplishes what I would like to do, but it's pretty verbose:

```rust
// Unstable features
#![feature(specialization)]

// Define a function for specialization
trait Foo {
    fn foo(self);
}
impl <T> Foo for T
where
    T: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    default fn foo(self) {
        println!("I am a generic function: {:?}", self);
    }
}
impl Foo for f64 {
    fn foo(mut self: f64) {
        self *= 2.;
        println!("I am a f64: {:?}", self);
    }
}

// Test things
fn main() {
    Foo::foo(1.2_f32);
    Foo::foo("a");
    Foo::foo(2.3_f64);
}
```

This produces

```
I am a generic function: 1.2
I am a generic function: "a"
I am a f64: 4.6
```

I'd like to write a piece of code that looks like:

```rust
// Define a function for specialization
default fn foo<T: std::fmt::Debug>(t: T) {
    println!("I am a generic function: {:?}", t);
}
fn foo(mut t: f64) {
    t *= 2.;
    println!("I am a f64: {:?}",t);
}
```

but I am not sure if this is possible.  Is there a way to simplify the above code and encode a function specialization without the use of traits?  If traits are required, is there a better way to simplify the code, so that less code needs to be written?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but this post reads like using traits is the way to go: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/specialization-of-a-simple-function/13020
But this post is from 2017, so I'm not sure if anything changed.